# people who have liked Blog post

Tags: blog

I have created my blog in SharePoint. I want to know if there is a way to view who has liked the post.

Amey.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013 from your blog, you can select the manage posts link which will list out all your posts. Then you can hover over the smiley face and a popup will show the names of who liked your post.

[image: Manage posts]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 Blog site, all posts are stored in "Posts" List. This list has a column "LikedBy" which stores the Users who has liked that post.